# C# Override abstract property with more specific type

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have a rather simple problem, but I can't find a proper solution anywhere. I would like to specify an abstract object CustomValues as property in my abstract parent class. However, the class inheriting from it should be able to use a more specific type as an object for this property CustomValues. At first I thought I would solve the problem by an interface, but unfortunately that didn't work out either. How do you do something like that, that it works?

```cs
public abstract class MyAbstract {
    public abstract object CustomValues { get; set; }
}

public class MyImplementation : MyAbstract {
    public override MySpecificClass CustomValues { get; set; }
}
```

This will throw me three errors:

- Missing implementation for getter
- Missing implementation for setter
- Type missmatch between type `object` and `MySpecificClass`

Comment: Research derived generic class. This is what you are looking for. [this will get you started](http://www.functionx.com/csharp2/collections/Lesson04e.htm)

Comment: `object` is a *very* bad return type. You'll have to cast the result to specific types, always risking a bad cast. Create a generic method instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Problem is, that this CustomValues property will be serialized by JSON.net. I just want to make sure, that all derived classes do have a CustomValues property.

Comment: A derived class cannot be less capable than its base class. (This is related to the Liskov Substitution Principle.) `MyAbstract` has the ability to have any object assigned to its `CustomValues` property; you cannot narrow this in `MyImplementation`.

Comment: A generic type will solve that problem as well. The type parameter could determine the type of  `CustomValues`. If the property must have a value for the object to be valid, it should be a constructor parameter.

Comment: @StackOverthrow So is there a way to achieve my goal? @Mong Zhu's idea seems to be a neat trick, but `public abstract T CustomValues` in the base class doesn't work either.

Comment: Why doesn't that work?

Comment: @StackOverthrow Type or namespace "T" not found.

Comment: You need to define T: `public abstract class MyAbstract<T>` (and probably `public abstract class MyAbstract<T> where T: class`)

Comment: FWIW, C# 9 will have [a feature that allows for covariance like this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#covariant-returns).

Comment: @JoeSewell Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested in the comments would look something like this. (I'm assuming `CustomValues` should be a collection of something.)

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public ICollection<T> CustomValues { get; set; }
}
```

Or to ensure `CustomValues` itself cannot be reassigned, but can be accessed and added to:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public ICollection<T> CustomValues { get; } = new List<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your original thought that use an interface (+ generic) was at the correct direction. In general you might want to add type constraints as well.

```
public interface ICustomValues {
  ....
}

public class MySpecificClass : ICustomValues {
  ....
}

public abstract class MyAbstract<T> where T : ICustomValues {
   public abstract T CustomValues {
     get;
     set;
   }
}


public class MyImplementation: MyAbstract<MySpecificClass>  {
  public override   MySpecificClass CustomValues { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all guys. I found the solution by using a generic **properly**:

```
public abstract class MyAbstract<T> {
    public abstract T CustomValues { get; set; }
}

public class MyImplementation : MyAbstract<MySpecificClass> {
    public override MySpecificClass CustomValues { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You may not need a derived class at all. (Just guessing that you thought you needed that because you didn't know how to use generics before.)

Comment: @StackOverthrow The class is used to control an API via REST, which generates reports. Depending on the document type (which is defined by a string parameter, absent in my minimal example), CustomValues must contain different values. So my idea was to define an abstract class and then a specific implementation for each document type. Can this be solved better/simplier?

Comment: I suggest reading about the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and asking a question about what you're really trying to do.