# More specific property type through new keyword sanity check

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have a similar problem to [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63850852/c-sharp-override-abstract-property-with-more-specific-type), however I've found that using generics introduces unnecessary verbosity in actual use.

(In my case, "MySpecificClass" uses one specific ICustom Values type, so T would always be just one type.)

My current "solution" is to define a backing member in the base class, and then define "new" properties that cast to the more specific type in the derived classes as such.

```
public class BaseMember { }

public class BaseOwner
{
    protected BaseMember _member;
    public BaseMember member {get => _member; private set => _member = value;}
}

public class DerivedMember: BaseMember { }

public class DerivedOwner : BaseOwner
{
    public new DerivedMember member {get => (DerivedMember) _member; private set => _member = value;}
}
```

This feels very clever, and so far has not caused any issues. It also produces the exact interaction I'm looking for in terms of writing the higher level code that derives these classes.

**It also looks like a huge time bomb**, though I can't put my finger on it. What am I missing?

Comment: For an explanation of side effects of method hiding, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25363002/5803406)

Comment: While the current accepted answer is the correct way to deal with this situation in newer c# versions, but this link actually provided me with the information I was looking for. Looks like I'm safe (in my use case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# 9.0 allows to change the return type, use a more specific class. So you don't need `new`. See [Covariant returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns).

To use that you need to declare it as `virtual` in the base class and then `override` in the child.

Comment: Dang. This does exactly what I want without the weird casting accessors. It's a shame my application is stuck with 7.3 for reasons(tm).

Comment: @ThaHypnotoad: "because reasons". I know! That's a bummer. Good luck working with the stakeholders to convince them it's not fine to be stuck in the past.